# Computing tensor products of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'd like to compute $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}^{n}$, for some natural number $n$, and $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}$ $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$Tensor commutes with direct sum, so $\Q \otimes \Z^n \cong \Q \otimes (\Z \oplus \dots...\oplus \Z) \cong \Q^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for the first one, tensor product is distributive with respect to a finite sum. As for the second, write $1=\frac{n}{n}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The tensor product is also distributive for infinite direct sums. Not that it's relevant here, but useful to know.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I wasn't sure, so I preferred not ti risk it =)

Comment: So for the second, I could show it comes out to 0 since the elements all cancel?

Comment: Right, it's zero